# Why am I getting error 2005 - unable to read file using Azure Form Recognizer?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

Using Azure Form Recognizer v2.

Built model with files on azure blob.

As far as I can tell accounting for all items that are listed in various quickstarts.

When I do my GET with the Operation-Location uri to see results I receive error 2005 - Unable to read file.

Thinking access to blob somehow but I'm not seeing an issue.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you able to successfully train a model? A valid model is required prior to posting an analyze request. For analyze requests, you have two options to specify your input file (single file, no batch mode):

1. As a byte stream.
2. Via a SAS URL in the body of the request.

Which one did you try?
Please refer to the quickstart for more details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/curl-train-extract#analyze-forms-for-key-value-pairs-and-tables

Comment: I was able to get it working. I had a model. I think I may have been putting my input file information in incorrectly. It seemed to start working when I changed from private on my blob but I just tried to recreate with blob as private like in most examples and it worked ok. My first time using blobs and SAS URL. I will try a couple more attempts to recreate. Experience helps but I will say it would be nice to have a little more info in the error message of what the problem actually was. Thanks!